# Change .sprint.png file name in Liferay 6.0.6

Tags: liferay, sprite, liferay-6, siteminder

Liferay Portal Version : 6.0.6

In Liferay portal, I am trying to change the file name of the autogenerated .sprite.png file name to something which doesnt start with period(.)

Reason being Siteminder does not allow file starts with period(.)

I checked in 6.1, there is a portal property which we can set

```
sprite.file.name=_sprite.png
sprite.properties.file.name=_sprite.properties
```

Do you guys have any idea on how to change this in the older version prior to 6.1?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting these values in 6.0.6? I see these two properties in 6.0 PropsValues.java too. Can you try and report back?

Comment: I did check this, I didnt see the change. Still we have files starting with period(.) like .sprite.png, .sprite.gif etc.